# Add color picker to category attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, category-attribute

Does anyone know how to add a custom color picker attribute to categories?
I've tried the following code in an upgrade-script, unhappily without success.

```
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'color', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Farbe',
    'class'         => 'color {required:false, adjust:false, hash:true}',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));

$this->addAttributeToGroup(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'color'
);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a custom input renderer for your attribute.

So first add this to the install script:

```
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'color', array(
        'input'         => 'text',
        'type'          => 'varchar',
        'label'         => 'Farbe',
        'required'      => 0,
        'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible'       => 1,
        'input_renderer'=> '[module]/adminhtml_helper_color',
        'group'         => 'General Information'
    )
);
```

Now you need to create the input renderer.

`app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/Helper/Color.php`

```
<?php
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_Helper_Color extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Text
{
    public function getElementHtml() {
        $html = parent::getElementHtml();
        $html .= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            $('".$this->getHtmlId()."').color = new jscolor.color($('".$this->getHtmlId()."'));
        </script>";
        return $html;
    }
}
```

And you need to add the js for color picker in the page.
Add in one of your layout files in the admin this:

```
<adminhtml_catalog_category_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <js>jscolor/jscolor.js</js>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_category_edit>
```

Clear the cache and you are done.

Comment: It's not working. Can you please help me?