# Magento-2.1x need to add color picker on system config in admin pannel

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

I need to add `color picker` on the admin panel of `magento2.1`. I have added the color picker for `Magento-2.0x` and it works well.

Could any one suggest me the idea for `magento-2.1` ?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40903/add-color-picker-to-category-attribute works?

Comment: let me check it

Comment: No it didn't help me

Comment: This will work for you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91316/magento-2-custom-module-color-picker or http://webkul.com/blog/add-color-picker-magento2-system-config/

Comment: No, it's not working, those all work for Magento2.0x and not for magento2.1

Comment: This will work for you

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103316/magento-2-how-to-add-color-picker-in-admin-configuration-options/156037#156037

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I got the output,
Need to do two changes,

1)In the Test\Color\Block\Color.php,

Add the path in require.js , 
require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"],

```
    namespace Test\Color\Block;
    class Color extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
    {
        /**
         * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
         * @param array                                   $data
         */
        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
        ) 
        {
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }
         /**
         @param  \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
         Input  : add color picker in admin configuration fields
         Output : return string script
         */
        protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
        {
            $html = $element->getElementHtml();
            $value = $element->getData('value');

            $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
                require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) {
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        var $el = $("#'.$element->getHtmlId().'");
                        $el.css("backgroundColor", "'.$value.'");

                        // Attach the color picker
                        $el.ColorPicker({
                            color: "'.$value.'",
                            onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                                $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
                </script>';

            return $html;
        }
    }
```

2) In the app/code/Test/Color/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml.
Please do remove .js file.

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
        </head>
    </page>
```